# Can not add iframe into page with contentscript chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I'm writing a chrome extension and in contentscript, I try to append an iframe into page. Src of iframe is my html file. But it couldn't load the iframe, it showed 'page not found' instead.

```
 $('<iframe />');
  $('<iframe />', {
    name: 'frame1',
       id: 'frame1',
      src: 'iframe.html'
  }).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this function to recieve the correct path

```
chrome.extension.getURL("iframe.html");
```